# How to display a worksheet on a form in excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to display a worksheet on a form, but until now i did not succeed. The worksheet it contain 15 columns and about 2000 rows. Can someone help me?

Comment: How about inserting a `ListBox` into the form and the setting the `RowSource` to the data you want to display? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251646.aspx If you prefer you can also use a `ListView`: http://www.xl-central.com/fill-a-listview-on-a-userform.html Alternative answers are here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904696/put-a-user-form-directly-on-the-excel-sheet AND here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527540/how-to-display-part-of-excel-on-vba-form

Comment: when i use the ListBox  it's only displaying me the first column. For the ListView i get the error ",ethod or data member not found". and for the two other link you post i tryed to adapt the code from the last one to my needs, but isn't working.

Comment: you can use the property of a listbox, "ColumnCount", and give it the number of the columns in your sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a form with a listbox on it, and also a button.  Then put this code into the form module.  The button should have the name CommandButton1 and the listbox should be named ListBox1.

Finally on the listbox control change the columncount to 15.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' Activate the sheet that has the data you want displayed in the listbox
    Sheet1.Activate
    ' Put the range of the data you want displayed.
    ' Here I used columns "A" to "O" and 2000 rows
    ListBox1.RowSource = "A1:O2000"
End Sub
```

Comment: still there it's a problem i notice just now the listbox isn't showing all the columns. i was trying the lines code for another sheet wich have 17 columns and it's only show me 15 columns. I also added this ListBox1.ColumnCount = 17, but it's not working

Comment: Open the form in the editor.  Look at the properties box.  You have physiclaly change the property in the properties box to 17.  You can't do it with code.